# Fluid image using percentage: how do I make the correct approach?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I've been reading about fluid layouts and came across a very good article that can help me to achieve what I need right now. It is about fluid images using percentage instead of `max-width`.

**A Better Fluid Image Solution:** http://demosthenes.info/blog/586/CSS-Fluid-Image-Techniques-for-Responsive-Site-Design

> *For example, let’s say you had an image that had a natural size of 500px × 300px in a 1200px wide document. Below 1200px, the document will be fluid. The calculation of how much width the image takes up as a percentage of the document is easy: (500 / 1200 ) × 100 = 41.66%*

It sounds perfect for what I need, but there is one thing I dind't understand: how do I tell the browser that the image should take up 41.66% of the document ONLY when width is BELOW 1200px? If i simply set `<img src="something.jpg" style="width: 41.66%;>` it will make the image always take up 41,66%, and I need this to happen only below 1200px wide.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would media queries to do this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
img {
    width: 500px;
}
@media ( max-width 1200px ) {
    img {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .img2 {
        width: 42%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Josh, thank you for your help. I'm still wondering how to set different %s for different images using media queries. Do I have to create a different @media for each image (`@media.image1`, `@media.image2`), and then apply to my HTML (style)?

Comment: No, consider the media query as a wrapper for all your css which will be effected by that window size.

You could just throw many .class lines within a single media query.

Comment: This is what I'm trying: `@media ( max-width 1280px ) {.img-logo-resized {width: 18.04%; } }` and `<img src="images/logo.png" class="img-logo-resized">` but when I view the website with my smartphone, the logo doesn't resize. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this perhaps viewing the site on landscape? It is possible your phone is actually exceeding that 1280px limit.

Comment: I've found a way: set the max width and height of the image based on the real size of it: `<img src="images/content/como-fazemos-content-1.png" style="width:100%; max-width:184px; max-height:227px;" />` Thank you anyway.